# Receiving Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have an activity that opens txt files.  And everytime a user wants to open a txt file, my app will be able to open it.  My question is, how do I pass the path of the file to be opened to my activity?  And, how do I receive the path programmatically?  In short, what are the things I have to do besides setting the intent filter in the manifest file to allow my app to open a txt file upon clicking that file?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what you mean by "click a txt file". What interface are you using to display the files? How are you determining which file is clicked?

Comment: I will be displaying the file with a text view wrappened within a scroll view, and I will be clicking the file via a file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a Broadcast Receiver, but not sure what intent-filter you have to use.

Maybe something to try is adding something like this to your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_PICK" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you need to create your MyBroadcastReceiver class like this:

```
public final class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    // Your receiver code here...
  }
}
```

And then check into the onReceive method the data received into the Intent when you try to open a file. That way you may know what data will arrive into the Intent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have a question regarding registering this MyBroadcastReceiver.  Do I instantiate a new IntentFilter to put in the registerReceiver() method? Or is there a way to get the Intent Filter from the Manifest file?

Comment: You can configure the intent-filter directly in your manifest file, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the File ( http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) or FileInputStream ( http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html) classes to hold file paths and handle input. If you are passing by intent you will probably want to use the putExtra() method to add a string containing the filename to the intent and retrieve it on the other side.

Comment: I am not passing an intent.  I was referring to the intenet Android system itself passes when you click on a file to be opened.  Do I have to use a Broadcast Receiver or something?